# Wireless printer going offline upon entering power save mode

Tags: network-printer, laser-printer, powersave

I recently bought a printer, a Samsung ML1865W wireless laser printer. It works very well, wirelessly until after a while, it goes to power save mode when the printer goes offline. I then cannot connect to the printer (pinging the IP and various ports associated with it do not give any response) until I power cycle the printer.

I have checked my wireless settings and my router, I have installed the printer software in WinXP, Win2000 and in Mac and the printer behaves just the same. Any ideas if the printer hardware itself is broken or that its something on my network/application side that's the culprit. If you own the printer, have you had any trouble like that at any time?

Comment: I still have not found any solutions to this issue yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new firmware fixed it - (ver.V3.xx.01.08). Firmware at http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/ML-1865W/XAA